# Is it possible to change facebook "like" button with a custom icon?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I really dont like how facebook like button integrates within the site, so I am wondering is it possible to pass all the possibilities form the "like" button to a different div as a custom icon.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with the css of the like button, but I suggest against it.

There are 2 reasons:

1. Users are used to that like button, it's what they know and trust, it's what their eyes are looking for when they want to like the page.
2. Facebook changes things quite frequently, and so if you are playing with the css definitions then you need to keep stay up to date with all of the updates, and those updates are not reported.

Comment: I want to change it entirely its like the same as to put the "like" button possibilieties to a banner or etc. Imagine the marketing possibilities of that :)

Comment: I believe that marketing wise it makes more sense to use what everyone are used to, but it's not based on any facts/statistics. Good luck with hacking their css.